# How can I convert ServiceStack.HttpResult to Response in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

Servicestack's `AuthService` is designed for REST style http response. Because of that 
`AuthService.Post(auth)` returns `HttpResult`.So you can easily consume it via JQuery + Ajax.

But if you want to use it with classic Asp.Net MVC :

```
public ActionResult Login(Auth auth)
{
    HttpResult result = (HttpResult)AuthService.Post(auth);
    // YOU HAVE TO CHECK IF LOGIN SUCCESSFUL THAN 
    // IF SUCCESSFUL YOU HAVE TO REDIRECT IF IT HAS REDIRECTURL PARAMETER

    //if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Found)
    return View();
}
```

So How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just re-factured AuthService and added the [Authenticate()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthService.cs#L185) method to make it easier to call from C#.

Returning null means user was already authenticated (and no attempt was made). Returning non-null means the user authentication was successful. Any Authentication failure will throw an exception.

With this change you will now be able to do:

```
public ActionResult Login(Auth auth)
{
    try {
        AuthResponse result = AuthService.Authenticate(auth);
        var alreadyAuthenticated = result == null;
        return alreadyAuthenticated
          ? View("success")
          : View("alreadyAuthenticated");                 

    } catch(Exception ex) {
       return View("authError");
    }
}
```

These changes will be in the next version of ServiceStack (v3.84) on NuGet. Until its published you will have to build from the [main repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack).